# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have added below code to Insert/Update record into table

```
public void createFacebookAccessTokenRecord(int userId, Long facebookId,
            String token, String secret) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        UserAuthDetails userAuthDetails = (UserAuthDetails) session.get(
                UserAuthDetails.class, new Integer(userId));
        if (userAuthDetails != null) {
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookId(facebookId);
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookUserToken(token);
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookUserTokenSec(secret);
            session.merge(userAuthDetails);
        } else {
            userAuthDetails = new UserAuthDetails();
            userAuthDetails.setUserId(userId);
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookId(facebookId);
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookUserToken(token);
            userAuthDetails.setFacebookUserTokenSec(secret);
            userAuthDetails.setCreatedDt(new Date());
            session.save(userAuthDetails);
        }


    }
```

If data exist it will update table otherwise Insert into a new record,in my case data already exist so i am updating record so first if loop working but i am getting

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate
>   entry '482186425258498' for key 'umul_facebook_id_UNIQUE'; SQL [n/a];
>   constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
>   '482186425258498' for key 'umul_facebook_id_UNIQUE'

Answer (score 1):

you are looking up by `userId` and unique constraints gets violated about `umul_facebook_id`, so you need to check the uniqueness of `FacebookId` as well

Comment: Only one record in table and facebookid is null thats why i am updating it

Comment: Just Search in DB with this code `SELECT * FROM subodhc_ccc.user_auth_details where facebook_id=48218645258498;` no record exist

Comment: I mean try through the same code, it might be cached or somewhere in session

Comment: Ok but but `session.merge()` should work if exist then update otherwise insert ..same i tried `session.saveorupdate()`

Comment: I mean right before merge or update, try to read the instance by it, or else try enabling sql logs and see if it is querying before failing, what is the query to troubleshoot